# Tomcat crashes when i call native function a number of times

Tags: java, tomcat, java-native-interface

I am working in a program which uses a c++ code .The code dll is called using native function.The code takes a file around 9MB and performs certain operation and creates a file of arount 2MB in certain location.

The program is running well when i send a single file but when i send multiple file, then it stops the server.What might be the problem any hint to move on?
I am using netbeans 7 with tomcat 7 Jdk 1.6.

```
  System.load("C:\\library.dll");  

  Classname.native_class(Input_file_path, Created_file_Path);
```

Class Classname:

```
    public class Classname {
     public native static int native_class(String Input_file_path, String Created_file_Path);
```

}

Comment: Clearly you have a bug in your native code.  However, it is not wise to load a native library via an app server like tomcat(or Jboss) as any segfault will crash the whole server.  Best to move that logic out into its own JVM, accessible via RMI calls or some other method.

Comment: @Samhain But sometimes it works fine.But most of the time it works for only 1 or 2 file.And that native code was successfully used in doing same operation using c#.

Comment: I simply did it by increasing the connection time attribute in tomcat server.Any way thanks

Comment: @mahesh, I experience the same behavior, it works well for many month but as long as I add load to my node it crashes entire tomcat. Have you found a solution?